# Using Barcode ID for Event Management

Tags: php, windows, open-source, barcode

I have a barcode scanner and laptop (ofcourse :)), I'm looking for simple event management app that can process the input from the barcode scanner and keep attendance record for our frequent private meetings.

I wonder if there's an open source software available that'd allow me to manage events using code 128 barcode id cards?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DIY. Seriously, this would be a perfect project to do. If you're inclined that way!

If you have a barcode scanner that follows some standards in interfacing (serial etc.) and protocol then PHP will be able to read the data. After that it's plain sailing!

EDIT: Seems like amazon sells barcode readers that act like keyboards. This makes interfacing the least of your problems!

Comment: Great, can you link me to those keyboard please. Thanks!

Comment: This one looks to be the most popular and very cheap: http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B000QGSUUK/ref=s9_simh_gw_p23_i2?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_r=0F23RZ5K88CHZBPEHBJ2&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=467198433&pf_rd_i=468294

Comment: Great, can you please also help with the php backend. Is there any opensource app that I can use/modify?

Comment: Simple and effective, not that I know of. What would be your basic functionality?

Comment: Code 128 ID card scanning. Matching against a list (could be just a .txt) of IDs to make sure its valid ID. Attendance: Marking Y or N (eg. 150410 /t Y) by date. Here again, its okay if just a .txt is generated for each date/event, no interface required. Thanks!

Comment: That's nice and simple. If you want to collaborate then leave a message :)

Comment: Leave a message where? SO doesn't seem to have PM functionality.

Comment: Update your account info with a URL/email somewhere for a brief moment so I can scrape it.

Comment: Ok, visit this link: http://bit.ly/9GSOdg

Comment: Got it - you can remove your link!

Answer (score 1):

Choose a scanner that acts as a keyboard and automatically translates the code 128 to a series of numbers followed by a "return". That way you could use any ol' spreadsheet, website or even Notepad to keep track of your meetings.

Look at Drupal and the many plug-ins that are available there. There are complete conference kits that you should be able to use. I think going for that kind of monster solution  will just complicate matters - the relative simple task involved taken in to account...